# Math behind, $MSE = bias^2 + variance$

Tags: variance, bias, estimators, mse

Based on the `deeplearningbook`:

$$MSE = E[(\theta_m^{-} - \theta)^2]$$

$$equals$$

$$Bias(\theta_m^{-})^2 + Var(\theta_m^{-})$$

where m is the number of samples in training set, $\theta$ is the actual parameter in the training set and $\theta_m^{-}$ is the estimated parameter.

I can't get to the second equation. Further, I don't understand how the first expression is gained.

Note:

$Bias(\theta_m^{-})^2 = E(\theta_m^{-2}) - \theta^2$

Also how bias and variance evaluated in classification.?

Comment: See this. the proof is explained https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

The proof for this has been clearly explained on [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship)

[image]

For more detailed discussion please refer to this [Question on stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/mse-decomposition-to-variance-and-bias-squared)